# Configure Micronaut application in the services Intellj

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

In IntelliJ we have an option to run the application in the services. I have a microservice Micronauts application trying to register in the services tool, however there is no option for the micronaut application

[image]

[image]

How can register in the services section.

If I select as application and run as a compound from the edit run configuration, it never runs in the services

[image]

It never starts the application, however, the application is running

Comment: `I have a microservice Micronauts application` what run configuration do you use to run it?

Comment: Application, but if I do application the services are not running the application

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Is it about Services tool window not displaying the Application run configuration or something else?